# How to target a top-level link in a multi-level unordered list?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multi-level nav styled as an unordered list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="nav-menu">
  ...
  <li id="menu-item-1">
    <a href="#">Category</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-2">
        <a href="#">Sub-Category</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

The top level is styled so that there is a background when hovered. My problem is that this background disappears when the cursor moves to the sub-menu. I'm trying to use jquery to add a class to the top-level anchor when its sub-menu is hovered. Any suggestions?

Sample of pertinent CSS:

```
#menu-nav li a { /* no background-set */ }
#menu-nav li a:hover { background: #fff; }
.sub-menu li a { background: #ccc; }
.sub-menu li a:hover { background: #999; }
```

Comment: Any example of stylesheet would be nice. (Normally, if child is hovered, parent is considered 'hovered' too)

Comment: @Nikita, added relevant CSS; @K accepted top answers on my unanswered questions even though they didn't actually solve my problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the primary `<li>` to retain styling while hovering secondary links, you'll need to apply your `:hover` style to the `<li>` rather than the `<a>` within it.

**JS**

```
$("#nav-menu > li").hover(
    function(){ $(this).addClass("hover"); },
    function(){ $(this).removeClass("hover"); }
)
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-menu li:hover, #nav-menu li.hover {/* styles here */}
```

Don't forget to neutralise `#nav-menu li:hover` styles on the secondary `<li>` elements. You could use `#nav-menu > li:hover` I guess but the browser support isn't as strong.

Comment: Even simpler than I thought. Thanks, champ.

Answer (score 2):

@Tyler , try to use Mouseenter , Mouseleave instead of mouseover and mouseout , that will fix your problem

http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: my problem isn't with jquery events, but with actually traversing the lists.